# Redirecting to setup page problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3

I'm trying to access my already existing website that was clone from our repository. Now upon access it keeps on redirecting me to the Setup page. I'm not sure what happen but I already some suggested that the local.xml is missing. Now I'm not sure how to generate it or where to get it.. Also I'm already using our DB so it's not a fresh DB copy. How can I solve this? It keeps on redirecting me to the setup page.

Comment: Are u facing the issue on Magento2? There is no local.xml in m2

Comment: Yes in magento 2.3.1.. What will be the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've previously only encountered this issue once. On a cpanel server we set the web root as /public_html/pub instead of/public_html as per recommendations in magento guidelines before running install wizard.

The website kept redirecting to the setup wizard page. The solution was to set web root back to default and then install via command line. The install process checks the setup table to work out where it is in terms of versions. Once installed reset it back again to public_html/pub clear cache and it seemed fine.

Install process generates db access files env.php etc which stops the redirection.

Although I'm assuming you've got a db in place and can connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the env.php with configs.

[env.php reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-envphp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here on a fresh install.

The issue ocurring because the bin/magento setup:install was not finished properly.

After running again (fixing the errors that crashed the above command), everything worked as expected.